# Why can't I add a new series via Google Sheets App Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm attempting to dynamically the a new series in an embedded Google Sheets chart (after adding dynamically adding new rows of data). The chart range updates and the series definition partially updates, but it doesn't increase in size. E.g., I start with three series and I can change the configuration of the three series but my 4th series entry is always ignored. This is a bar chart:

```js
// build the new series
for (let i = 0; i < newProductCount; i += 1) {
  const labelInLegend = profitSheet.getRange(profitProductTableStart + 2 + i, 1).getValue()
  profitSeries.unshift({ color: colorSeries[i], labelInLegend })
}

console.log(profitSeries) // shows series with 4 entries

let profitsChart = getChart(dashboardSheet, 'Profits breakdown')
profitsChart = profitsChart.modify()
  .clearRanges()
  .addRange(profitSheet.getRange(profitProductTableStart, 1, newProductCount + 2, 13))
  .setOption('series', profitSeries)
  .build()
dashboardSheet.updateChart(profitsChart)
```

Original graph:
[image: Original bar chart showing Product A, Product B, and Product C]
After the code runs:
[image: The colors and label change, but the data does not update.]

Notice that the colors and legend labels have updated, but the bars have not and are actually out of sync with the legend. 'Product 4' / blue should be zero. No matter what I do, it only shows 3 series despite building a series of 4.

The data looks like this initially:
[image: Table showing profits of each product.]

and after the new product is added:
[image: Table showing addition of 'Product 4'.]

Row 7 is the label, then we skip 8 and our series come from rows 9, 10, 11 and then 12 after the new product is added.

In the chart settings, the range properly updates, but again the series only shows three entries rather than the four as defined. Why isn't the 4th series showing up in the graph?

Comment: Can you share sample data? What type of graphics are you using? Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: I ended up just rebuilding the chart rather than trying to modify the existing chart and that was much easier. But the question as to why modification doesn't work stands because it would be slightly preferred if we could get it working.

Comment: I did eventually realize that the 'labelInLegend' didn't select the series and rather than try to get it to skip rows (series) like I had done when manually building the chart, I moved the total to the bottom so all rows in the range are either labels or valid data. That worked when creating a new chart, but the fundamental problem if not being able to expand the series on modification persists.